# How to use anonymous functions?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

How can I properly use Anonymous Functions? I am trying use a generic compare function but I get the following error in the example bellow. Can someone explain why does this happen?

```
program Project11;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

type
  TSort<T> = record
  private
    type
      TCompare = reference to function(const L, R: T): Integer;
  public
    class procedure Sort(var A: Array of T; const First, Last: Integer; const Compare: TCompare); static;
  end;

{ TSort<T> }

class procedure TSort<T>.Sort(var A: array of T; const First, Last: Integer; const Compare: TCompare);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := Compare(1, 2); // [dcc32 Error] Project11.dpr(30): E2010 Incompatible types: 'T' and 'Integer'
end;

var
  A: Array of Integer;
begin
  TSort<Integer>.Sort(A, 1, 2,
  function(const L, R: Integer): Integer
  begin
    // Do something with L & R
  end);
end.
```

Comment: FWIW, `TArray.Sort<T>` in `Generics.Collections` implements this already. And also, FWIW, your compare function is no good. Imagine what happens when `L` is `high(Integer)` and `R` is `low(Integer)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan compare function can be anything thats the beauty of generics without any kind of interfaces.

Comment: You are reinventing things from `System.Generics.Collections` and `System.Generics.Defaults`.

Comment: You don't need to deal with any interfaces. You can just supply a compare function. And I don't call your compare function beautiful. I call it an overflow generator. Your entire code can be replaced by `TArray.Sort<Integer>(A)`. If you want to supply a compare function you use `TArray.Sort<Integer>(A, TComparer<Integer>.Construct(Comparison))` where `Comparison` is your anonymous method.

Comment: Also, +1 for a really good SSCCE with complete code and a full error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should actually want

```
I := Compare(A[1], A[2]);
```

or

```
I := Compare(A[First], A[Last]);
```

instead of

```
I := Compare(1, 2);
```

As TLama already mentioned: Compare expects two parameters of type T. A is an array of T, so you can supply its members. 1 and 2 however are integers.

The fact that you later on say that you want T to be an integer is not relevant at this point: If you can say at this point that your code ALWAYS will use integer as T, then you shouldn't use a generic

Comment: T will be anything not just an Integer.

Comment: @user3764855 Thought so (otherwise using a generic wouldn't make sense). So in that case `Compare(1, 2)` is definitely wrong.